# Does sbt support java 9?

Tags: java, sbt

After installing jdk-9.0.1 I tried `brew install sbt` but it failed and shows:

```
sbt: Java 1.8 is required to install this formula.
JavaRequirement unsatisfied!
```

Comment: Ran into a similar issue..https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/pull/143 was helpful

Comment: @Akshay not entirely sure if I can use it. Did you manually set a few environment variables to get it working?

Comment: yes..it's a tedious task..spend time if you really need this bad..it's better to use it on java8

Comment: @Akshay I think it might just be that 9.0.1 contains 0.1, so the installation package thinks the JDK is version 0.1.